# Принадлежность точки прямой

Tags: java, математика

Есть три точки, A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2), C(x3, y3), нужно узнать принадлежат ли они одной прямой, так же есть enum с видами функций, пока там только LINE(Линейная), а так же есть функциональный интерфейс, в котором есть метод function, и в зависимости от выбранной функции, высчитавается, принадлежат ли точки к одной прямой, но есть проблема, не знаю как написать решение на java, вот код:

```
//functionType.java

public enum functionType{
    LINE
}

//Coordinates.java

public class Coordinates{
    private final int x, y;

    public Coordinates(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x; 
    }        

    public int getY(){
        return y; 
    }

    //Вот в этом методе проблема:

    public boolean canMove(Coordinates point1, Coordinates point2, Coordinates point3, functionType type){
        if(type == functionType.LINE){
            Function function = (Coordinates point1, Coordinates point2, Coordinates point3) ->{

            }
        }
    }

//Function.java

public interface Function{
    public boolean function(Coordinates point1, Coordinates point2, Coordinates point3);
}
```

Как реализовать метод который в лямбда-выражение? Зарание спасибо!

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_to_line например. Можно просто проверить пропорциональность приращений.

Comment: Проблема в отм, что эту систему в жизни дегко решить, а в java я не знаю как, можно код пожалуйста

Comment: Блин (x1-x2)/(y1-y2)=(x1-x3)/(y1-y3). Только аккуратно записать.

Comment: @pavel Не хочу надоедать, но проблема в том, что я не понимаю как из этого уравнения мне получить булеан) Сори за тупость)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @pavel Не хочу надоедать, но проблема в том, что я не понимаю как из
>   этого уравнения мне получить булеан) Сори за тупость)

```
return (x1-x2)*(y1-y3)==(x1-x3)*(y1-y2);
```